# What *is* a GlobalTag MegaBlender™?

Tags: support, tags, tag-filters

I came across the [globaltag-megablender](/questions/tagged/globaltag-megablender) tag while handling a lost user.

Now, the tag *seems* to be about a specific thing. It just doesn't seem clear what that is. It's oddly consistent over how its used, but I have no idea what feature it is.

It lacks a tag wiki to boot.

It is mentioned in [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/66838#66838), but it doesn't feel like the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™

So what *is* (or *was*) the GlobalTag MegaBlender™?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) function on stackexchange.com.

You can use it to keep track of questions in certain tags *across the Stack Exchange network*.

IMHO, this tag should be merged into [tag-filters](/questions/tagged/tag-filters):

> Tag filters (AKA the Stack Exchange™ GlobalTag MegaBlender™), as seen at https://stackexchange.com/filters.

Comment: It's merged now

Comment: *votes to close question as 'can no longer be reproduced'...*

Comment: Amusingly - I was debating whether we needed the tag so I guess its handled.

Comment: @Rob No that's not what that question is about. Favorite and ignored were only mentioned as exampled of where wildcard was already supported. The [original announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68328/cross-site-tag-sets-are-live-feedback) is deleted for whatever reason, but outlines the very first bare-bones version of tag filters across the network.